# "System.UnauthorizedAccessException" when extracting file to Desktop

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I created a script to extract an executable file from the `Resources` to my Desktop. This works on my machine, but won't work on other's people machines because of a different username. The following script works perfectly:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    byte[] myfile = Properties.Resources.SOMETHING;
    File.WriteAllBytes("C:\\Users\\Alex\\Desktop\\SOMETHING.exe",myfile);
}
```

I did some some research and found that I need to use the
`(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop)`

So I compiled this script:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    byte[] myfile = Properties.Resources.SOMETHING;
    File.WriteAllBytes(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop),myfile);
}
```

The problem is that it doesn't say there is an error in my code, but when I run it and press on the button I get the following error:

> System.UnauthorizedAccessException Message=Access to the path 'C:\Users\Alex\Desktop' is denied.

I've tried running the code with administrator rights, but that also didn't help.

Comment: You try to write the bytes to a file having the same name as the Desktop folder. This does not work. Try `File.WriteAllBytes(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "myfilename.txt"), myfile);`

Comment: Have they tried running it as an admin?

Answer (score 1):

Use `File.SetAttributes(myfile, FileAttributes.Normal);` property before reading the file, it should work.

Comment: It states the following `Cannot convert Byte to string`

Comment: byte[] myfile = Properties.Resources.SOMETHING;                                   
string result = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(myfile);
File.SetAttributes(result , FileAttributes.Normal); 
 File.WriteAllBytes(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop),result );  try this it should work